# Como acessar a url da aba atual

Tags: google-chrome-extensão

Eu tenho parte deste código que pertence a uma extensão do chrome. 
Ao clicar no botão da partilha, não me partilha o conteúdo da página que pretendo.

Alguém sabe como faço para partilhar a página em que se encontra no momento do clique?

```
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxxx',
          xfbml      : true,
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          status     : true, // check login status
          version    : 'v2.0'
        });
      };

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

  if (d.getElementById(id))

      //var e = document.createElement('script');
     // e.src = document.location.protocol + 'all.js';
      //e.async = true;
     // document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      return
  js = d.createElement(s); 
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "sdk.js";
  js.async = true;
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

}



(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="fbbutton.js"></script>
        <script src="settings.js"></script>
        <style>
          div span, iframe {
            height:50px!important;
            width:100px!important;
          }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>


<div id="fb-root"></div>



        <div style="width:160px; height:200px; font: normal 21px/23px 'ProximaNovaSemibold',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
            <form id="share" action="" method="">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="share2" name="share" /> <span style="position:relative; top:3px;margin-bottom:20px;c">Quer partilhar no face?</span>
                </label>
               <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" style="width:100px; height:50px;"></div>
            </form>          
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa tarde Marta, não use o snippet desnecessariamente. Outra coisa você pode ler a documentação, por que se para cada detalhe do seu aplicativo, você vai criar uma questão, o que pode ser mais rápido de aprender, portanto *sempre* leia a documentação e estude por ela! :) Sucesso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2797972/1518921), leia sobre isto em:

- [Tab API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)
- [Browser Action API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)

Um exemplo de uso do seu arquivo js seria algo como:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    console.log(tab.url);
});
```

É necessário alterar o atributo `data-href` do seu botão de share:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" style="width:100px; height:50px;"></div>
```

Pode-se usar algo como:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    document.querySelector("div.fb-share-button").setAttribute("data-href", tab.url);
});
```

Comment: Ao obter o URL do email percebi que para partilhar é necessário obter o conteudo desse url. Para tal usei a função document.getElementById('share2').innerHTML=tab.data;     No entanto não estou a conseguir. Apenas preciso de palavras chave para pesquisar. Obrigado.

Comment: É verdade @Marta o facebook não consegue geralmente acessar URLs aonde há autenticação, mas se bem que pensando melhor, não tem por que compartilhar uma página autenticada. Porém o uso de `tab.data` ainda tem mais vantagens do que injetar o share-button por causa da "segurança", não que o facebook irá "roubar" acessar algo indevidamente, mas qualquer código injetado pode se tornar mais complicado, aonde por exemplo usamos autenticação (mesmo que a página seja publica, ainda sim pode haver autenticação).

Comment: Tentei fazer o pedido de permissão ao utilizador, mas algo não está bem.                                                 
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    document.getElementById('share2').innerHTML = tab.url;
    chrome.permissions.onAdded.addListener({permissions: ['tabs'], origins: ['http://www.google.com/']}) {
          console.log("The permissions are nedd.");
          document.getElementById('share2').innerHTML = tab.data;
         document.querySelector("div.fb-share-button").setAttribute("data-href", tab.url);
       });

});

Comment: @Marta isto já é outra questão. Se você seguiu a rigor os exemplos da documentação, por favor *abra uma nova questão*. Este link pode lhe ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Até logo :)